# Why is this implication true?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

$\dfrac{4x^2}{(1+x^2)^4} < 1 \to \dfrac{2\mid x \mid}{(1+x^2)^2} < 1$ . This is from a textbook i'm using (Advanced Engineering Mathematics, 10th ed., Kreyszig). It looks like the left hand side is the right hand side squared, and I understand how to show that the left hand side is true. But I don't understand why it implies the right hand side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $a^2 = \frac{4x^2}{(1+x^2)^4}$. Then we have: 
$$a^2\lt 1 \iff a^2 - 1\lt 0 \iff (a - 1) (a+1)\lt 0.$$
Clearly, $ a\in (-1,1)\iff |a| \lt 1$. But $|a|= \frac{2|x|}{(1+x^2)^2}.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $a < b  \implies f(a) < f(b)$ if $f$ is strictly increasing.  Here, $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Take square roots. When everything is positive, this preserves inequalities.